# Modifier doesn't work when used with .apply

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why is it that `border` modifier is not applied when used with `.apply { }`?

```kotlin
val selected = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

val selectableModifier = Modifier
    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    .apply {
    // this changes, but border is not applied
    println("$selected changed") 
    if (selected) {
        border(
            BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant),
            RoundedCornerShape(13.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`apply` always returns `this` to output. You can change `this` inside, but in case with modifiers they are immutable, you expected to create a new modifier based on the current one. That's why your `border` is being ignored.

Instead you can use `run`, and you have to return something: newly created modifier or `this`. Check out more about [kotlin scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html).

```
val selected by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

val selectableModifier = Modifier
    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
    .run {
        if (selected) {
            border(
                BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant),
                RoundedCornerShape(13.dp)
            )
        } else {
            this
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call a Modifier's method it returns the Modifier itself with new changes.
So you have to do something like that

```
var modifier = Modifier
modifier = modifier.doSomeThing()
modifier = modifier.doOtherThing()
```

OR use then

```
val modifier = Modifier
.then(Modifier.doSomeThing())
.then(Modifier.doOtherThing())
```

You can make conditional then extension method.

```
fun Modifier.thenIf(condition: Boolean, other: Modifier): Modifier =
    if (condition) this.then(other) else this
```

And use it like that

```
val modifier = Modifier
.then(Modifier.doSomeThing())
.then(Modifier.doOtherThing())
.thenIf(canClick==true,Modifier.doConditionalThing())
```